# Perform two operations using compare field validator

Tags: vb.net

I have a compare field valdiator associated with a TextBox `textbox1`. It compares its value to that of another TextBox, `textbox2`, to check whether it's value is less than that of the other.

Now, I also want to make sure that `textbox1` does not contain the value 0. So how can I apply this validation in the same comparefield validator?

Comment: Would it be possible to add a second, separate CompareFieldValidator which validates the same textbox, but with different criteria?

Comment: I have tried it, but its giving me two messages which is not good:
1.Minimum Acceptable Rent Amount Must Be Less Than The Asking Rent Amount  (validate with other textbox)
2. Please Specify Minimum Acceptable Rent Amount (compare with 0)

Comment: Ok. Then maybe you should look into using a CustomValidator instead, where you can call a separate function, which will validate both your cases, and return an appropriate message accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a RequiredFieldValidator for textbox1 and set InitialValue="0"

Comment: See the comments below the question; he would prefer to avoid two separate validators.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comments, you might want to try using a CustomValidator. [You will find some documentation here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.onservervalidate.aspx).

Oonce you've set up the validator, implementing your own function to check the value against that of the other textfield, and also for a value 0, should be a surmountable task! :)